# Why am I unable to use my increment operator overload? [C++]

Tags: c++

I have the following struct:

```
struct sequence_t {
    uint8_t val;
    explicit sequence_t(uint8_t value) : val(value) {}
    sequence_t() : sequence_t(0) {}

    auto operator++() -> sequence_t& { // prefix
        val = (val + 1) % 16;
        return *this;
    }

    auto operator++(int) -> sequence_t { // postfix
        sequence_t tmp{val};
        ++*this;
        return tmp;
    }

    uint8_t value() const { return val; }
    auto operator==(const sequence_t& other) const -> bool = default;
    auto operator==(const uint8_t other) const -> bool { return val == other; }
};
```

And I use it inside a class declared like this:

```
class messenger {
  private:
    sequence_t sequence;

  public:
    messenger() = default;
    ~messenger() = default;
    auto make_message(const uint8_t type) const -> std::shared_ptr<std::uint8_t[]>;
    auto make_message(uint8_t const* data, const uint8_t size) const -> std::shared_ptr<std::uint8_t[]>;
    auto parity(uint8_t const* buffer) const -> std::uint8_t;
};
```

I am calling the operator in the make_message() member of the messenger class because I want to update the value of the sequence (to the whole messenger object) when I create a message:

```
auto messenger::make_message(uint8_t const* data, const uint8_t data_size) const -> std::shared_ptr<std::uint8_t[]> {
    auto buffer = std::make_shared<std::uint8_t[]>(sizeof(header) + data_size + sizeof(parity(nullptr)));
    ++sequence;
    header h = {START, data_size, sequence.value(), TYPE_DATA}; // TODO: implementar sequência
    std::copy(std::bit_cast<uint8_t*>(&h), std::bit_cast<uint8_t*>(&h) + sizeof(header), buffer.get());
    std::copy(data, data + data_size, buffer.get() + sizeof(header));
    buffer[sizeof(header) + data_size] = parity(buffer.get());
    return buffer;
}
```

But when I try to use sequence++ or ++sequence inside the messenger class methods I get the following error:

```
error: passing ‘const sequence_t’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
[build]    17 |     ++sequence;
[build]       |       ^~~~~~~~
```

Why is it const? How can I modify the content of my sequence?

Comment: next time please create a [mre]. From the error message it looks like you try to use the operator on a const obejct.

Comment: `make_message` is a const method so `this` is const so `this->sequence` is const thus you can't use `++` on `sequence` here.

Comment: @bolov I am trying to use the operator on an object that should not be const, but I think that ```this``` is forcing it to be const somehow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
auto messenger::make_message(uint8_t const* data, const uint8_t data_size) const
```

That `const` keyword at the end signifies that this is a `const` class method. A `const` class method:

1. Can only call other `const` class methods
2. Cannot modify any class members
3. If any class members are objects, only their `const` methods can be called

(ignoring explicitly `mutable` class members, to avoid confusion)

`++sequence` effectively calls a `sequence`'s method. As per rule 3, it is not a `const` class method, hence the compilation error.

You have the following options:

- change `make_message()` to not be a `const` class method.
- given the sample usage here, it might be feasible to declare `sequence` as a `mutable` class member. You must fully understand the repercussions of doing so.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the overloaded increment operator on a `const` object, but the operator itself is not `const`.