# No viable overload '=' error when assign a value

Tags: c++, drag-and-drop, drag, qstring

I have a custom ListModel class. In this class, There are mimeData and dropMimeData methods. I'm trying to assign return values to QString in main class. But it throws an error.

[image]

I search about the error and it says

> You are getting the no viable overloaded error because of the reasons outlined below: You are passing a pointer in place of a string. You want to modify a const variable. You have used the wrong return value for cv::boundingRect in OpenCV.

I'm passing a QString to QString. What is the problem ?

[image]

Custom class .h file

```
class ListModel: public QStringListModel {

  public:
    using QStringListModel::QStringListModel;
    QString draggedData;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and replace images with code/error messages with text.

Comment: your function is marked as const so it is not supposed to modify data members

Comment: You can't modify the member `draggedData` from within the context of a `const` member function.

Comment: See similar question: [Why am I unable to use my increment operator overload?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73411416/12002570).

Comment: But when I remove the const, I cant override the method.

Comment: Create your own method for what you want to do, and call it when drag starts. QStringListModel is probably not the best place to handle your dragged data.
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID to learn more about Single Responsibility Principle